# Accent incorrectly displayed in ISO-8859-1 on Firefox with window.open

Tags: javascript, url, uri, iso-8859-1

In our application encoded in **ISO-8859-1**, I have javascript code that opens a window with the `window.open` command to display values with accents.

These accented values are not displayed correctly (for `é` I get `Ã©`). They are passed as a parameter in the URL of the window.

```
http://<SERVER>:<PORT>/<TOMCAT-CAR>/pages/script.jsp?prenom=Prénom
```

This problem only occurs on **Firefox** (under **IE** and **Chrome** the character is displayed correctly).

Do you know why there is this difference?

Comment: It seems the `é` char that you pass in the `window.open` is encoded as **UTF-8** which uses 2 bytes (`0xc3` and `0xa9`) for that char, then the `JSP` page converts it to the **ISO-8859-1** (shows the 2 bytes directly as they were 2 different chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before passing the string, encode it first using [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/encodeURI), and when you fetch the result decode it before using it using [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/decodeURI).

Comment: Thanks, I use decodeURIComponent to format variable in URL of window.open command and convert them to ISO-8851-1 with URLDecoder.decode in the jsp open.